# trying to search for $\int_0^1 \ln x \;dx$

Tags: discussion, support, search

trying to search for $\int_0^1 \ln x \;dx$, as an example to be able to search, could not get any answers, is there a better way to search for this or that is as good as it gets for searching of latex?

Comment: I searched for "int log" and came up with [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/901796)